# how to get latest commit from all repositories in github

Tags: github, github-api

please share your comments to get all the Git Hub repositories and its latest commits filtered via curl or any API  or chrome postman?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All" the GitHub repo seems a bit far fetched (too many of them), but still, the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) allows you to [list all *public* repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories)

```
GET /repositories

# Get a list of github repos

curl https://api.github.com/repositories

# show just the headers

curl -D - https://api.github.com/repositories -o /dev/null
```

You also can use the **[search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories)** to filter a bit your repos, as illustrated in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jasonrudolph/6065289)

```
curl -G https://api.github.com/search/repositories
```